# Android Studio didn't install SDK

Tags: android-studio

I am encountering a strange behavior that I can't find any similar experiences on.  I installed Android Studio but I can't for the life of me figure out why it won't install the Android SDK.  The setup says I already have it installed, but the C:\Users\"user_name"\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk folder does not exist on my system (see image).

Has anyone encountered this?  Any assistance is appreciated.

[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEf8C.png)

Comment: Yep, I have the same issue.  I'm doing cordova builds and if I do the cordova requirements check it tells me that the SDK is installed on one line, then on the next line says it isn't...  :-/